# Erase Area Within Polygon in Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am using Tkinter in Python to draw a map. I would like to fill a polygon (currently using create_polygon) and then un-fill a small polygon area within it. Is it possible to do this?

This is a vague diagram of the sort of thing I'm thinking of:

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just draw another polygon _after_ the first but make it the same color as the background, or do you want a real hole?

Comment: @martineau I'm going to have an underlying image to add texture to the whole thing so I need a real hole.

Comment: As far as I know, tkinter doesn't support such multi-contour polygons.

Comment: You might be able to do it by using the [`pillow`](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) fork of the PIL module and its [`PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill) method to create an image and then use it in `tkinter` (which is [supported](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/ImageTk.html#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage)).

Comment: @martineau So I'd create an image out of whatever I'm doing with polygon borders drawn and then fill the areas that I want to fill?

Comment: Yes, that's the basic idea. You'd also need to make the image have a transparent background so the area(s) `floodfill()` didn't fill in would be transparent and allow whatever's beneath it to show through.

Answer (score 2):

You may not be able to actually do this, but you can certainly fake it: duplicate two of the points (one on the outer and one on the inner contour), so that you have a single polygon with two of its edges coincident.

[image]

Obviously, this is only going to look right with a fill specified, not an outline...