Polygon within a polygon TkinterMapView
how to implement a polygon inside a polygon without overlapping?
I would like to split an area into multiple polygons, but I'm running into a problem.
What I have
Example of what I wan
The method of traversing the area along the contour did not help.
When explicitly specifying coordinates and creating two polygons, one overlaps the other.
What I got by creating two polygons
Upd:
I managed to do what I set out to do.
Answer the question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071801/erase-area-within-polygon-in-tkinter-canvas]
Here is the answer to my question. I used these settings for the polygon, as stated in the answers.
map_widget.set_polygon(polygons.all_polygons.conditionally_save_zone, fill_color='yellow', outline_color=None, name="csz")
outline_color=None - allows you to not highlight the polygon joints
[Example] (https://i.sstatic.net/zeUPU.png)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
